Making a border-bottom or underline extend past text
I am trying to figure out how to extend the border-bottom of this element so it matches the mockup, but I can't seem to do it. It only really goes under the text part.
How can I make it so that it extends to the entire box/underlines half of the nav bar?
Here's what it's supposed to look like:
(https://i.sstatic.net/fLeaH.png)
Here's the HTML:
<nav class="nav">
            <ul class="nav__list">
                <li class="nav__item nav__logo"><img src="./assets/logo/Logo-bandsite.svg"></li>
                <li class="nav__item nav__links">
                        <a class="nav__link nav__link--bio" href="./index.html">Biography</a>
                        <a class="nav__link nav__link--shows" href="">Shows</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

and the scss:
.nav {
            &__list {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 5rem;
            padding-top: 1.3rem;
        }

            &__logo {
                padding-bottom: 1.2rem;
            }

            &__links {
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-around;
            }

            &__link--bio {
                font-weight: $bold;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding-bottom: 1rem;
                border-bottom: 3px solid $primary-white;
                border-width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
}


And here's what I'm getting:
(https://i.sstatic.net/bf1vQ.png)
I also tried to put the  in a div and do the border on that, but it gave me the same result.
Thanks in advance.

Add this CSS rule:
.nav__links > * {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

It will widen the width of the links – and thereby its bottom border! – to 50% of the parent element. Without that, the links will only be as wide as their text, the space around them is created by the justify-content: space-around; setting but is not part of the link elements themselves.


body {
  background: #555;
}

.nav__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 5rem;
  padding-top: 1.3rem;
}

.nav__logo {
  padding-bottom: 1.2rem;
}

.nav__links {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.nav__links>* {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav__link--bio {
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  border-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav__list">
    <li class="nav__item nav__logo"><img src="./assets/logo/Logo-bandsite.svg"></li>
    <li class="nav__item nav__links">
      <a class="nav__link nav__link--bio" href="./index.html">Biography</a>
      <a class="nav__link nav__link--shows" href="">Shows</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>



